# Why std::mutex of c++11 has no memory order?

Tags: c++, mutex, atomic, memory-barriers, stdmutex

I mean compared with c++11 atomic, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> counter(0);

void incrementCounter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(incrementCounter);
    std::thread t2(incrementCounter);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "Final counter value: " << counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the usage of `std::atomic`, we need to pass memory order parameters. Why doesn't `std::mutex` have this parameter and what's the default memory order of `std::mutex` ?

Comment: "Relaxed" essentially means "only operations on this atomic are synchronized, but not on data accesses to other variables before or after". For mutex, that would be rather pointless - the only reason to use one is to synchronize access to other variables. Locking and unlocking a mutex necessarily implies acquire/release semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct usage of mutexes gives sequential consistency for data-race free programs (if they don't use any atomics weaker than `seq_cst`), even though the mutex lock / unlock themselves are only acquire and release operations.
(This is where the names come from for [those lock-free atomic memory orders](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).)

So there's no need to make them stronger.

And as Igor pointed out, they'd be useless if any weaker than release and acquire: relaxed would give no ordering wrt. operations on other variables, so wouldn't contain them to critical sections.

`std::memory_order_consume` instead of `acquire` wouldn't be usable because you can't read the mutex value to use it as part of the address calculation for a later load.  (If you want to mess around with a lock designed that way to see if it's viable, you'd have to roll it yourself using `std::atomic`, but current compilers promote `consume` to `acquire`. It's currently deprecated: the original design proved too hard to implement correctly + efficiently, and too cumbersome to use with std::kill_dependency, etc.)

Comment: *"promote `consume` to `relaxed`"* Is this a typo, they promote to acquire, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: yup, just a typo, was in mid thought about how the Linux kernel still takes advantage of the underlying hardware behaviour using effectively relaxed and writing the code in a way that doesn't give the compilers they care about any reasonable way to optimize away the data dependency.  e.g. avoiding stuff like `ptr[x-x]` to do `*ptr` with a data dependency on `x`.  But decided not to mention anything about that since you *would* want to do that sort of thing to introduce a data dependency on the flag value for a semaphore if you were attempting that.